# Orchard Custom MembershipService and UserService

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I am creating a new module to authenticate users against a custom MembershipService.  I have made copies of the MembershipService and UserService from the Orchard.Users module and added the OrchardSuppressDependency attribute to each.  I also created a custom data access service and injected this into each.  My first step is to replace the ValidateUser method.

The existing method uses a ContentManager query to retrieve the UserPart from the Orchard database.

```
public IUser ValidateUser(string userNameOrEmail, string password)
    {
        var lowerName = userNameOrEmail == null ? "" : userNameOrEmail.ToLowerInvariant();

        var user = _orchardServices.ContentManager.Query<UserPart, UserPartRecord>().Where(u => u.NormalizedUserName == lowerName).List().FirstOrDefault();

        if (user == null)
            user = _orchardServices.ContentManager.Query<UserPart, UserPartRecord>().Where(u => u.Email == lowerName).List().FirstOrDefault();

        if (user == null || ValidatePassword(user.As<UserPart>().Record, password) == false)
            return null;

        if (user.EmailStatus != UserStatus.Approved)
            return null;

        if (user.RegistrationStatus != UserStatus.Approved)
            return null;

        return user;
    }
```

I need to create a UserPart with data from my own repository.  I attempted the following and no exceptions are thrown, but the user is not logged in.

```
public IUser ValidateUser(string userNameOrEmail, string password)
    {
        UserPart user = null;
        var userRecord = _userRepository.GetUserByEmail(userNameOrEmail);

        if (null != userRecord)
        {
            user = _orchardServices.ContentManager.New<UserPart>("User");
            user.Record.Email = userRecord.Email;
            user.Record.EmailChallengeToken = userRecord.EmailChallengeToken;
            user.Record.EmailStatus = userRecord.EmailStatus;
            user.Record.HashAlgorithm = userRecord.HashAlgorithm;
            user.Record.Id = userRecord.Id;
            user.Record.NormalizedUserName = userRecord.NormalizedUserName;
            user.Record.Password = userRecord.Password;
            user.Record.PasswordFormat = userRecord.PasswordFormat;
            user.Record.PasswordSalt = userRecord.PasswordSalt;
            user.Record.RegistrationStatus = userRecord.RegistrationStatus;
            user.Record.UserName = userRecord.UserName;
        }

        if (user == null || ValidatePassword(user.Record, password) == false)
            return null;

        if (user.EmailStatus != UserStatus.Approved)
            return null;

        if (user.RegistrationStatus != UserStatus.Approved)
            return null;

        return user;
    }
```

Is there a way to populate a UserPart without a ContentManager query?  I also posted on the Orchard discussion forum [here](http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/264466).

Comment: did you finally get it to work? I've been trying to do something similar.

Comment: No, I haven't had any luck yet. The record is retrieved and the password validates, but Orchard doesn't log in the user.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you read the code for DefaultContentManager very closely. I don't quite understand what you are trying to do, but you don't need to do "As" on user, as it already is a UserPart.

Comment: I have an existing user database and I'm trying to get Orchard to authenticate with. I tried creating a CustomUser class inheriting from IUser, but the UserContext expects a UserPart rather than an IUser. This is my first attempt at integrating with Orchard, so any pointers would be apprectiated.

Comment: Right, so as I said, you don't need to do user.As<UserPart>() as this object already is a user part. Try to do user.Record instead.

Comment: Did you step through it with a debugger to see what path it goes through?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure GetAuthenticatedUser() method present in file FormsAuthenticationService.cs returns your user as expected.